# Embedded resource in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a c# windows application where I use sharppdf.dll to create pdf files on the fly.
I have embedded certain bitmaps in my application by doing the following:

1. Right Click Bitmaps and choose "Add Existing Item"
2. Add the bitmap you want
3. In the bitmap properties change "Build Action" to "Embedded Resource"

Then to include the bitmap I do the following:

```
sharpPDF.pdfDocument myDoc = new sharpPDF.pdfDocument("TEST", "ME", false);
sharpPDF.pdfPage     myPage;

Stream _imageStream;
_imageStream = _assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("MyClass.Bitmaps.ArrowUp.bmp");
Image img = new Bitmap(_imageStream);
myDoc.addImageReference(img, "ArrowUp");
myPage.addImage(myDoc.getImageReference("ArrowUp"), nX + 60, nY);
```

Now I wish to convert my application to the web, my question is how do I 'embed' my bitmap images in my C# asp.bet web application??
Or is there a different concept that I should use?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please tell us exactly what you tried and what troubles you ran into.

Comment: What happened when you tried to convert your application to a web application? Did you get any error message or other types of problems?

Comment: I am trying to create a new image similar to what I'm doing above. I have copied the images I want to include into a folder images/pdf and have tried the following:                                           Image img = new Bitmap("~/images/pdf/ArrowUp.bmp");
myDoc.addImageReference(img, "ArrowUp");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the fundamental difference here between Windows apps and Web apps, is that you own/control the files that are being used.

Whereby in a Windows app you had to include the files into the assembly that the user installed, in a Web app you can maintain the files in a separate folder within the application itself.

So, in your case here is the code I believe you are looking for:

```
using System.Drawing;
Bitmap img = new Bitmap(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\[IMAGE FOLDER]\[IMAGE NAME]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It completely depens on what you want to do with the images.

If those are part of the interface you want to show to the user, you simple put them all into a folder and reference them in your ASP.NET pages with HTML and CSS, like you would in a normal website.